# Micca OriGain AD250 output device intermittently recognized/not recognized

Tags: 18.04, usb, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I am attempting to use a [Micca OriGain AD250](https://www.miccatron.com/micca-origain-compact-integrated-amplifier/) integrated Amp/DAC as an audio output device on Ubuntu 18.04, but I'm running into an issue with the device being recognized.

I currently have it connected to my computer via USB. When the device is on, it shows up as both an analog and digital output device in sound settings for about one second, then disappears for about half a second, and repeats the process ad infinitum. During the second that it is recognized, audio comes out of the speakers just fine.

Any recommendations on what to do? I've tried implementing several fixes that were given for audio devices not being recognized, but none have worked for me.

Comment: Any error messages in the system log when this happens?

Comment: @CL. Here are the most recent log messages (apologies for bad formatting):

`9:23:45 AM upowerd: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0
 9:23:44 AM kernel: usb 1-6: reset full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
 9:23:44 AM upowerd: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.1
 9:23:44 AM gsd-media-keys: Unable to get default sink
 9:23:44 AM pulseaudio: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP with snd_pcm_prepare(): No such device`

Comment: Please show more messages. (Click "edit" to edit the question.)

Comment: @CL. I should have mentioned in the previous comment, but these exact messages just loop over and over every two seconds. I've simply posted one cycle since my character length was limited. There was one point over a 12 second interval I got the message `9:23:37 AM pulseaudio: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Got POLLNVAL from ALSA` right before `9:23:37 AM pulseaudio: [alsa-sink-USB Audio] alsa-util.c: Could not recover from POLLERR|POLLNVAL|POLLHUP with snd_pcm_prepare(): No such device` but it didn't show up again anywhere else.

Comment: If there aren't any other messages, then it's probably the device itself that decides to do a reset. The default CM6510B firmware should not do stupid things like this, so I suspect a hardware problem. Does it work with another cable, on another PC, or with Windows?

Comment: @CL. I don't have another PC to try it on, but I did try another cable and it didn't fix anything. Also, it runs perfectly fine on Windows.

Comment: Please try different USB ports (USB 3 sometimes makes a difference, one way or the other).

Comment: @CL. Just tried every USB port (USB 2 and USB 3). Still no luck.